# Add icon to main contextual menu' in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, context-menu

I'm used to open CMake project by right-clicking on the content of the folder, then select in the context menu that appears `Open With Visual Studio`.

In Windows 11, I need an additional passage, because I right-click on the content-folder, then I select the last option in the context menu ("Other Options" maybe, I'm using the Italian version of windows and I don't know what it exactly says in English), then a Windows 10 style contex menu appears with all the options and I can select `Open With Visual Studio`.

Is there a way to move a choice from the secondary context menu in the main one? So I can open without an additional passage.

Comment: Windows 11 is very limited for context menus